# Best way to save an image?

Tags: c#, file-upload

I have an asp.net mvc application that allows images to be uploaded. I am wondering what is the best way to do it.

Right now I have this

```
HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImg = Session[SessionImgKey] as HttpPostedFileBase;

if (uploadedImg != null)
{
    string fileName = CreateFile(MyField.Name, uploadedImg);
    tableA.ImagePath = String.Concat(ImgFolderPathLoctaion, "\\", fileName);
}
```

This is fine but I want to move it my service layer and I don't want to have in import a web.dll into my service layer project.

So should I be using a stream? or something like [Image Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) (I think this might be more geared for images through the paint class not images uploaded.

Comment: Why are your uploaded file stored in a session?

Comment: I have a jquery formwizard that gets posted by ajax (using serialization). Since posting a file with ajax is not possible(without using a iframe or html5). I had to use plupload so they have to hit the upload button it gets stored in a session and when they submit the whole form I get it out of the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image stream from the posted file, convert it in an image (System.Drawing) and then save it:

```
var stream = uploadedImg.InputStream;
var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
//convert stream into image
Image myImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer));
myImage.Save("c:\myimage.jpg");
```

Comment: Is this better than using a stream reader/writer and writing the bytes?

Comment: The InputStream property of the HttpPostedFileBase gives you back the stream of the uploaded file so you don't need a stream reader, the Save method of the Image write on a file the content of the buffered image, same thing is done with the stream writer. The result is the same.

Comment: Should I use the same file extension that was uploaded or you think I should force a standard(save everything as a jpg for instance?)

Comment: Also should anything be wrapped in a using statement?

Comment: Same file extension. Search online for examples of the usage of the Image class and give it a try.

Comment: How is this vs using File.Create() then write it to it?

Comment: You are just saving a file,response is the same of the second comment, there is pratically no difference in both the performances and the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the file down to your service layer, use the [InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream.aspx) property of HttpPostedFileBase to pass a stream. By doing it this way, your service layer does not know of your web/presentation layer.

Comment: This is what I will do but I am unsure what the best way to write it to the server? Use a stream reader and writer?